# Teradata CMICAutoscalingGroup Error When Using Cloud Formation in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, teradata, aws-cloudformation

We are receiving a CMICAutoscalingGroup group error when using Cloud Formation to spin up a Dev/Test environment.  We have tried this multiple times and validated that:

- The VPC/subnet are configured correctly (Can see both in and out; We all opened all TCP ports)
- Setup Security Group with TCP (and at the end set all to open)
- Made sure that SNS, AutoScaling and other permissions as assigned as full for the user creating the environment
  We have tried creating a new VPC and different versions of the database and different regions

The error occurs about 1/2 hour to 45 minutes into the stack starting.  Below are events from the log.s

Errors:
**The following resource(s) failed to create: [CMICAutoscalingGroup]. . Rollback requested by user.
Received 0 SUCCESS signal(s) out of 1. Unable to satisfy 100% MinSuccessfulInstancesPercent requirement
Failed to receive 1 resource signal(s) for the current batch. Each resource signal timeout is counted as a FAILURE.**

Logs:

> ROLLBACK_COMPLETE AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  TeradataEcosystemTestdevEnterprise
>   DELETE_COMPLETE   AWS::IAM::Role  DBMppRole
>   DELETE_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::IAM::Role  DBMppRole
>   DELETE_COMPLETE   AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup DBSecurityGroup
>   DELETE_COMPLETE   AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup EcosystemSecurityGroup
>   DELETE_COMPLETE   AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile   DBMppInstanceProfile
>   DELETE_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup DBSecurityGroup
>   DELETE_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile   DBMppInstanceProfile
>   DELETE_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup EcosystemSecurityGroup
>   DELETE_COMPLETE   AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration   DBLaunchConfig
>   DELETE_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration   DBLaunchConfig
>   DELETE_COMPLETE   AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup  DBAutoscalingGroup
>   DELETE_COMPLETE   AWS::IAM::Role  CMICRole
>   DELETE_COMPLETE   AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup CMICSecurityGroup
>   DELETE_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::IAM::Role  CMICRole
>   DELETE_COMPLETE   AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile   CMICInstanceProfile
>   DELETE_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup CMICSecurityGroup
>   DELETE_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile   CMICInstanceProfile
>   DELETE_COMPLETE   AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration   CMICLaunchConfig
>   DELETE_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration   CMICLaunchConfig
>   DELETE_COMPLETE   AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup  CMICAutoscalingGroup
>   DELETE_COMPLETE   AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup VPSecurityGroup
>   DELETE_COMPLETE   AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress  DBSecurityGroupSelfRule
>   DELETE_COMPLETE   AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress  CMICSecurityGroupSelfRule
>   DELETE_COMPLETE   AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress  EcosystemSecurityGroupSelfRule
>   DELETE_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup VPSecurityGroup
>   DELETE_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress  DBSecurityGroupSelfRule
>   DELETE_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress  EcosystemSecurityGroupSelfRule
>   DELETE_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup  DBAutoscalingGroup
>   DELETE_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup  CMICAutoscalingGroup
>   **DELETE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress  CMICSecurityGroupSelfRule
>   ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  TeradataEcosystemTestdevEnterprise
>   CREATE_FAILED AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup  CMICAutoscalingGroup
>   UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup  CMICAutoscalingGroup** CREATE_COMPLETE  AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup  DBAutoscalingGroup
>   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup  DBAutoscalingGroup
>   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup  CMICAutoscalingGroup
>   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup  CMICAutoscalingGroup
>   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup  DBAutoscalingGroup
>   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup  DBAutoscalingGroup
>   CREATE_COMPLETE   AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration   CMICLaunchConfig
>   CREATE_COMPLETE   AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration   DBLaunchConfig
>   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration   CMICLaunchConfig
>   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration   DBLaunchConfig
>   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration   DBLaunchConfig
>   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration   CMICLaunchConfig
>   CREATE_COMPLETE   AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile   DBMppInstanceProfile
>   CREATE_COMPLETE   AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile   CMICInstanceProfile
>   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile   DBMppInstanceProfile
>   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile   DBMppInstanceProfile
>   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile   CMICInstanceProfile
>   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile   CMICInstanceProfile
>   CREATE_COMPLETE   AWS::IAM::Role  DBMppRole
>   CREATE_COMPLETE   AWS::IAM::Role  CMICRole
>   CREATE_COMPLETE   AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress  CMICSecurityGroupSelfRule
>   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress  CMICSecurityGroupSelfRule
>   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress  CMICSecurityGroupSelfRule
>   CREATE_COMPLETE   AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress  EcosystemSecurityGroupSelfRule
>   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress  EcosystemSecurityGroupSelfRule
>   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress  EcosystemSecurityGroupSelfRule
>   CREATE_COMPLETE   AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup CMICSecurityGroup
>   CREATE_COMPLETE   AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress  DBSecurityGroupSelfRule
>   CREATE_COMPLETE   AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup VPSecurityGroup
>   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress  DBSecurityGroupSelfRule
>   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress  DBSecurityGroupSelfRule
>   CREATE_COMPLETE   AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup DBSecurityGroup
>   CREATE_COMPLETE   AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup EcosystemSecurityGroup
>   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup EcosystemSecurityGroup
>   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup VPSecurityGroup
>   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup DBSecurityGroup
>   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::IAM::Role  DBMppRole
>   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup CMICSecurityGroup
>   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup EcosystemSecurityGroup
>   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::IAM::Role  CMICRole
>   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::IAM::Role  DBMppRole
>   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup VPSecurityGroup
>   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::IAM::Role  CMICRole
>   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup CMICSecurityGroup
>   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup DBSecurityGroup
>   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  TeradataEcosystemTestdevEnterprise

Comment: Can you provide your cloudformation template?

Comment: We are using the standard template from TD.     I cannot add the template here...too big.     https://us-east-2.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/designer/home?region=us-east-2&templateUrl=https://teradata-aws.s3.amazonaws.com/templates/ecosystem_testdev_enterprise_existing.json

Comment: This is a link to your AWS console where you're already logged in